# How to count ifs from .c file?

Tags: c

I need some help to finish my code. The program needs to find all the ifs from a .c file and count them. So far I'm able to find all if strings which are followed by '(' (because ifs have a '(' after them ) but now I'm worried that there might be something which ends with if and is followed by '(' and it will be counted as well (a different function or something like that). So I had the idea to check if there is something before the 'i' and if there is nothing I'll count it but if there is some kind of character I won't. So my question is whether my idea is good or not? If its good how to do it ? And if its not good what can I do?

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *file = fopen ("poohzad.c", "r");
    char *ch = NULL;
    int i=1;
    if (file != NULL){
        char line [256];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL){
            if (strstr(line, "if")){
                ch=strstr(line, "if");
                if(*(ch+2) == '(') printf("%s\n", line);
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
    fclose (file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could at least indent it correctly ....

Comment: You are very close. Try this: what class(es) of characters immediately before your `if` will make it something else than a plain `if`?

Comment: Don't forget that whitespaces between tokens are ignored and you need to take that into account. For example, your program currently does not detect cases where there is no space after the `if` or if there is more than one space after the `if`.

Comment: What if the source code contains the following: `const char *str = "if(if(if(if"`

Comment: There could also be `if`s as comments: `// if(something)`. Maybe you're suppose to count them as well?

Comment: You should also take into account that the `(` character after the if can be in the next line, or after several lines. There are also other cases way more difficult to detect, for example `char * str = "if(x==5)";` or `#define FOO if` and afterwards `FOO(i == 0)` but you may want to ignore them.

Comment: `strstr` will never work. You'll find the string "if" in all sorts of places that aren't `if` statements. You're going to have to build the basics of a parser that can break code up into tokens based on C syntax rules and `strstr` is much too crude for that. Lookup `strtok` and `strpbrk` for insight.

Comment: Something like flex would be very useful to you.

Comment: You also will need to account for quoted strings and things like that, say there's a string which just so happens to have an if () as its output, or something else weird which ends in that pattern- as Carey said, you'll need to create a parser of some kind - flex might be overkill but is easy enough to get started with. This isn't as simple as it first appears.

Answer (score 0):

most error checking where omitted. use it at your own risk. (formatted using AStyle, so no comments about that please)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ifs;

/**
   loads an ascii file, returns NULL on failure
*/
char *loadFile(char*fname){
    char *buff;
    int len;
    FILE *fd;
    fd=fopen( fname,"r");
    if(!fd){
         printf("error opening file '%s'\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    fseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    len=ftell(fd);
    fseek(fd,0, SEEK_SET);
    buff=malloc(len+1);
    fread(buff,1,len,fd);
    fclose(fd);
    *(buff+len)=0;
    return buff;
}

/**
  placeholder what to do with the word
*/
void addWord(const char *word){

    if(0)
        printf("'%s'\n",word);
    else
    if(!strcmp(word,"if"))
        ifs++;
}


/**
    is operator simplified
*/
int isop(char c){
    static char list[]=
    "_"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "0123456789";
    return !strchr(list,c);
}

int main(){
    char *pbuff,*buff,*ptr,c;
    int pos;
    pbuff=loadFile("main.c");
    buff=pbuff;
    ptr=pbuff;


    while(c=*buff){
        switch(c){
            case '?':
                if(0){
                    addWord("if");
                }
                ptr=&buff[1];
                break;
            case '#':
                while(*buff && *buff!='\n'){
                    if(c=='\\') buff++;
                    buff++;
                }
                ptr=&buff[1];
                break;
            case '/': //comment?

                //single line comment
                if(buff[1]=='/'){
                    buff+=2;
                    while(*buff && *buff!='\n'){
                        if(*buff=='\\')buff++;
                        buff++;
                    }

                    //multi line comment
                }else if(buff[1]=='*'){
                    buff+=2;
                    while(*buff && !((buff[-1]=='*') && (*buff=='/'))){
                        buff++;
                    }
                }else{
                    //not a comment, just ignore it;
                }
                ptr=&buff[1];
                break;
            case '\"': //skip strings
            case '\'':
                buff++;
                while(*buff && *buff!=c){
                    if(*buff=='\\') buff++;
                    buff++;
                }
                ptr=&buff[1];
                break;
            default:
                if(isspace(c) || isop(c)){
                    if(ptr-buff){
                        *buff=0;
                        addWord((const char*)ptr);
                        *buff=c;
                    }
                    ptr=&buff[1];
                }
        }
        buff++;

    }

    // take habit to free memory
    free(pbuff);
    printf("there are %d ifs in source file\n",ifs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing `break` for the # case?

Comment: Thanks you for the fast response! I think i understand most of the code but i cant figure out why you o this " ptr=&buff[1];  "

Comment: @Roronoa ptr=&buff[1]; ptr point always to the beginning of the word, if we skip current char, than it will be pointing the the next word that start from current pos+1, thus address of buff[1];